# Could not able to load data of API in AURA component

Tags: apex, api, aura

APEX CONTROLLER

```
public with sharing class GetUsersData {
    public class User{
        public String id;
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public String title;
        public String photo;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<User> getUsers() {
        Http  http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('app-id', '646354a050baed9c418991f8');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        List<User> users = new List<User>();

        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200){
            Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            List<Object> usersData = (List<Object>) results.get('data');
            for(Object userData : usersData){
                Map<String,Object> userDataMap = (Map<String, Object>) userData;
                User user = new User();
                user.id = (String) userDataMap.get('id');
                user.firstName = (String) userDataMap.get('firstName');
                user.lastName = (String) userDataMap.get('lastName');
                user.title = (String) userDataMap.get('title');
                user.photo = (String) userDataMap.get('picture');
                users.add(user);
                System.debug(user.photo);
                System.debug(user.firstName);
            }
        }
        System.debug(users);
        return users ;
    }

}
```

//AURA COMPONENT

```
<aura:component controller="GetUsersData" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">

<aura:attribute name="users" type="List" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:card>
        <div style="border: 1px solid #E3E3E3; margin:5px; border-radius: 5px;">
        <lightning:card  title="User">
            <aura:set attribute="actions">
                <div onkeyup="{! c.handleKeyUp }">
                    <lightning:input
                        aura:id="enter-search"
                        name="enter-search"
                        placeholder="Enter the Tag or Name"
                        type="search"
                        style="margin-bottom: 20px;"
                    />
                </div>
            </aura:set>
        </lightning:card>       
        </div>
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
            <!-- <p>hii {!v.users}</p> -->
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.users}" var="user">
                <p>Name: {!user.firstName}</p>
                <p>picture link: {!user.photo}</p>
                <!-- <img src="{!user.photo}" alt="{!user.firstName} Avatar" /> -->
                <hr/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
    

</aura:component>
```

```
//JAVASCRIPT

({
    handleKeyUp: function (cmp, evt) {
        var isEnterKey = evt.keyCode === 13;
        if (isEnterKey) {
            var queryTerm = cmp.find('enter-search').get('v.value');
            alert('Searched for "' + queryTerm + '"!');
        }
    },
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getUsers");
        console.log(action);
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(state);
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                 component.set("v.users", response.getReturnValue());
                
            } else {
                console.error("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties in a Data Transfer Object (DTO) should be AuraEnabled and have a getter and setter:

```
public class User {
  @AuraEnabled public String id { get; set; }
  @AuraEnabled public String firstName { get; set; }
  @AuraEnabled public String lastName { get; set; }
  @AuraEnabled public String title { get; set; }
  @AuraEnabled public String photo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer and also for edit the question. because i have no experience about how to post question here.